# Embedding Google drive PDF with Zoom Parameter

Tags: html, pdf, google-drive-api

I have found some old posts about this but none has solved my issue.

I try to embed some Google Drive PDFs in my website and zooming them to fit horizontally one frame.

Tried the code provided by google:

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/my_pdf_id/preview" width="640" height="1080">
</iframe>
```

Also found this one suggested as better:

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=my_pdf_id&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="580px" height="480px">
</iframe>
```

I can change the frame size, but pdf size is always the same. Tried other zoom parameters but none works, looks like Google viewer doesn't accept them.

Some pdfs are large with small text, and must be scrolled all down to see the zoom buttons down the pdf, which is quite annoying.

Stucked in this. Does anybody know any working way to show PDF itself in a zoomed or bigger size?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64309

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=your_pdf_id#view=FitH" width="640" height="1080"></iframe>
```

Comment: For reference - the `fith` means `Fit Horizontally`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `allowfullscreen="true"`

```
<iframe src="link" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```